# Getting Exception as No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, vb.net, exception, import, oledbconnection

I am getting exception as **No value given for one or more required parameters**.
If I use colsToBeSelected = "* "  (commented now), it's working fine but with current code I am getting error.

```
using (var cmd = _oleDbConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.Both;
            var sheets = _oleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

            var entityName = typeof(TEntity).Name.ToLower();
            string colsToBeSelected = "";

             if (entityName.IndexOf("alternate_credit_card") > -1)
                colsToBeSelected = isHeaderRowExists ? "[CardRefID], [Key], [MIS_Field1], [MIS_Field2], [ValidatingCarrier], [OtherCarriers], [Card Vendor], [Card], [Expiration], [Precedence], [AlertEmail], [maxTktAmt], [IRP_remark] "
                    : "[F1] AS [CardRefID], [F2] AS [Key], [F3] AS [MIS_Field1], [F4] AS [MIS_Field2], [F5] AS [ValidatingCarrier], [F6] AS [OtherCarriers], [F7] AS [Card Vendor], [F8] AS [Card], [F9] AS [Expiration], [F10] AS [Precedence], [F11] AS [AlertEmail], [F12] AS [maxTktAmt], [F13] AS [IRP_remark] ";
            //colsToBeSelected = "* ";
            else
                colsToBeSelected = isHeaderRowExists ? "[Value]" : "[F1] AS [VALUE]";

            var sqlQuery = "SELECT " + colsToBeSelected + "FROM[" + sheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] ";

            cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

            using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                excelDs = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(excelDs);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Screenshot of error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ8yg.png)

The file has below header columns

[headerfile(columns)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usbfw.png)

Comment: The command I end up building is 
SELECT [CardRefID], [Key], [MIS_Field1], [MIS_Field2], [ValidatingCarrier], [OtherCarriers], [Card Vendor], [Card], [Expiration], [Precedence], [AlertEmail], [maxTktAmt], [IRP_remark] FROM [Sheet2$]

Comment: I fixed the sql query but it still didn't work, I have attached the excel sheet screenshot which I am trying to import, I have double-checked the columns, they are identical and same, yet It's not working

Comment: What happens if you remove the (int not null) etc bits?

Comment: I am wondering, one of the column in the excel has column as Card Vendor(space b/w the two words), should I [Card Vendor]? or is there any other format

Comment: I removed (int not null) data types from the excel file, and ran again... it didn't work either

Comment: I'd suggest removing all of the column names from the code and adding them in one at a time (to narrow down which column is causing the issue).

Comment: The excel file has spaces before the name, I removed it and it worked, is there a way to make spaces optional here?